# Floating image over same location as background image responsively

Tags: html, css

I have an dynamic div displaying some information that I want to position in an exact position relative to the background of the page. For example, I want to put a number 9 let's say, over the eye of a cat. In "full" resolution, this works fine, but tying the margin-left to a pixel size, or even a percent, will cause this to break. The code for the "eye" is something like this:

```
.catEye {
  position: absolute;
  color: #DCDCDC;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "helvetica-neue-bold", helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 68px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Here is a plunkr that displays the problem. The problem is most evident at smaller resolutions. When in "full" resolution, the "9" should be directly over the cat eye.

http://plnkr.co/edit/2uqIhBseRLo5A47JVI2F?p=preview

I am using Foundation for the block-grid setup, 5 items per row. As the image I have is a certain size, this should generally remain the same if possible.

**Question:** Is there a way to get the "9" to always position directly over the eye, no matter the browser resolution? In my actual work, it needs to be positioned directly over a corner piece, so movement is very noticeable.

**Clarification:** After thinking about it, what I'm basically asking is positioning relative to the image element, because no matter the size/placement of it, as long as the "9" is placed relative to it, it would work.

Comment: post some other CSS (at least the one of  `div class="imgCat"` )

Comment: I added the exact question. @maioman There is a demo link provided that shows the issue, there's really not much more other than filler text on the item. The "9" should position EXACTLY over the eye, no matter the resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you meant to have sort of `background-size:cover` for the cat, I don't think that is possible in that case.

Currently, the `relative` position is set on the element that can be larger than `200px` (which is the image size), and you have `center` value set on the background, so that it moves. The cat eye is always staying in the same place but not the cat image.

To fix it, you can set the `relative` element to `max-width: 200px;`. Simplified demo follows.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6d0n80mt/)**

```css
.imgCat {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/qpbY8VC.png");
    max-width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.catEye {
    position: absolute;
    left: 75px;
    top: 95px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgCat">
    <span class="catEye"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: The background image is not cover, the actual piece has considerably more space around the centered background image.

Comment: You have the closest answer, there was one additional element I needed though. In order to place the element, I first centered it by using a margin-left 50% on the catEye. This places it right in the middle with the image. At this point, I now ALWAYS have a fixed distance from the center to wherever I'm going. Using "left", or "right" I can now position it from there as desired. As noted, imgCat must be relative positioned so that catEye absolute positioning works off the parent element. Thanks for that! Note also that other than the 50% margin-left, no other % should be used with responsive.

Answer (score 1):

**First** thing you can use `left:` and `top:` property to position an absolute/relative img (instead of `margin-left` & `margin-top`).

**Second** depending on how the containing img is resizing I'd set the `left:` and `top:` property with a percentage value.

**Third** use relative positioning (relative to static parent - like in your scenario).

---

put this in your CSS and let me know if it's the desired rendering

```
.imgCat {
   background: url('http://i.imgur.com/qpbY8VC.png') center no-repeat;
   height: 200px;
 }

 li {
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #000;

 }

 .catEye {
  position: relative;
  color: #DCDCDC;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "helvetica-neue-bold", helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 35%;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

BTW: actually the cat img doesn't look very responsive...